# Getting different logged in user on mac

Tags: python, macos, terminal

I am fetching the loggedin user using below function in my python script on mac terminal.

```
user = os.getlogin()
```

This gives me correct user for most of time which my user id. But many times it also gives user as "`_spotlight`". I am not sure if it is an issue with mac terminal.

Does anybody know what is a `_spotlight` user?

Comment: It's presumably related to the search software: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spotlight_(software)

Comment: See also: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2499466?start=0&tstart=0. As this is Apple-specific, you could also consider http://apple.stackexchange.com/